# SQL Query to get Average time

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I have 4 columns in my database

UserName, Date, Time, LoginType

```
UserName is a varchar field
Date is a date field
Time is a time field (in 24 hour format)
LoginType is a varchar field
```

LoginType can contain one of the two strings "LOGIN", "SHUTDOWN"

I want to get the average time someone will LOGIN or SHUTDOWN
I also want to know the delta of the lateless, earliness.

So for this example, lets assume that students must attent class by 8:30 and must LOGOFF by 10:30

So lets also assume the sample data is as follows

```
George.Lucas 8:45 2011-07-22 LOGIN
Eric.TheRed 9:00 2011-07-22 LOGIN
Dr.Who 9:01 2011-07-22 LOGIN
Dr.Who 11:01 2011-07-22 SHUTDOWN
George.Lucas 11:45 2011-07-22 SHUTDOWN
Eric.TheRed 12:00 2011-07-22 SHUTDOWN
```

1. We can see that George was 15 min late and he shutdown 1hr 15min late
2. Eric was 30 min late to login
3. Eric was 2hr 30 min late to SHUTDOWN
4. Dr.Who was 31 min late LOGIN
5. Dr.Who was 31 min late SHUTDOWN

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible there will be duplicate user names in the data like from multiple sessions?

Comment: Yes its possible for there to be multiple records for the same person for the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the average time a given user took between login and shutdown, even when there are multiple sessions for the same day, and assuming the user needs to shutdown before logging in again:

```
SELECT login.UserName, 
  AVG(shutdown.Date - login.Date)
FROM table login,
  table shutdown
WHERE login.UserName = shutdown.UserName
      AND login.LoginType = 'LOGIN'
      AND shutdown.LoginType = 'SHUTDOWN'
      AND shutdown.Date = (SELECT MIN(t.Date)
                           FROM table t
                           WHERE t.UserName = login.UserName
                                 AND t.LoginType = 'SHUTDOWN'
                                 AND t.Date > login.Date)
GROUP BY login.UserName;
```

To find out the difference between the expected and effective login/shutdown time, you just need to subtract 8:30 and 10:30 from `login.Time` and `shutdown.Time`, respectively.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the response. But I see your calculations give the difference between SHUTDOWN and LOGIN. I need the average between two LOGIN's on different dates (like 7.22.2011 thru 8.3.2011). Also need the AVG between SHUTDOWN's

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for but since no one else knows. I'll "accept" your answer.